# Hearing some kind of screeching sound. Is it (not) normal?

Tags: hearing, ear

Once in a while I hear some sort of screeching sound, sort of like that unpleasant sound heard when you scratch a sharp object against a chalkboard. Whenever I hear the sound, its sort of in a low tone, so it's as if the sound is either on my head or it's coming from somewhere very far away. Whenever I ask those beside me, they say that their not heating anything. So my question is:

**Is the sound coming from my head or I'm just the only one that could hear it?**

**Is such scenario normal or abnormal?**

**Is the sound simply produced by the wind passing by my ear?**

Comment: Is it pulsating? I had a similar situation a few years ago. It sounded kind of like a huge mosquito doing flybys near my ear. It was somehow my own bloodflow causing it.

Comment: This seems like a personal medical question. Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. To avoid closure, please try to edit the question so that it is generic. Personal questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see this [meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here/258).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not only hear these sounds on windy days while outside, wWhat you are describing is most likely [tinnitus](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tinnitus/home/ovc-20180349) and not simply the wind passing your ear. While tinnitus is common, it is generally a sign of an abnormality in the auditory system. In most cases you are the only one who can hear it, but in some cases the ear makes sounds. These [otoacoustic emissions](http://www.audiology.org/news/otoacoustic-emissions-tinnitus-distortion-product-oaes-and-transient-oaes-interview-david-kemp) can sometimes be heard by you and others.